# How can I add a customized left navigation to page layout?

Tags: navigation, page-layout

I have developed a piece of code to create a vertical navigation and want to add it to the page layout. the code is in JavaScript. how can I do that?

-Shani

Answer (score 2):

Keerthi's answer will work great if you want to place your JavaScript on one page.  If you want to add it to a specific page layout, I would do it a little different.

Editing the actual page layout or creating a new custom one would be best so you don't have to add your script to every page.  To do this you will have to use SharePoint Designer.

1. In Designer, open your top level site and click on `Page Layouts` on the left navigation.
2. Here you can either copy/paste a new or edit an existing page layout.
3. Insert your JavaScript into the page layout (insert the code directly into the file or reference to your .js file).
4. Save the file and make sure it is checked in.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a javascript file using the content web part.

Edit page -> Add web part -> Media and content -> Content editor -> Add

Edit the source of the web part and add the following code into it:

```
​<script src="/sites/subsite/list/SiteAssets/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or else just add you code between script tags in CEWP:

```
<script>
YOUR JQUERY HERE
</script>
```